# template partial specialization of static fields initialisation

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, template-specialization

I'm attempting something like the following:

```
struct MyType { };

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    static const MyType * const sm_object;
};

template <>
struct Test<void>
{
    static const MyType * const sm_object;
};

template <typename T> const MyType * const Test<T>::sm_object = new MyType();
template <> const MyType * const Test<void>::sm_object = new MyType();
```

I include this in 2 files - a.cpp and b.cpp. I attempt to compile and get:

```
error C2998: 'const MyType *Test<void>::sm_object' : cannot be a template definition
```

I assume my C++ syntax is bad, but I can't think what I'm doing wrong.

I can't remove the `template<>` from the variable definition, as I need this in multiple translation units, and that would result in a link error.

I could put the field into a base class and use the CRTP to create a new instance per type, and then the specialization wouldn't get in the way, but why doesn't this 'direct' field initialisation work? I must be missing some piece of syntax.

I'm using VS2003 :(

Comment: The answer is correct, but I ended up using a new struct TestHolder<T> which holds sm_object, and then only needing one static initialisation for the holder class instead of the partially specialised one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from g++ I think you need to remove the `template<>` from that line and put the remainder *in just one source file* (not in the header). Since it's a specialization it's just like a normal non-template static which you don't define in a header.

In some `.C` file:

`const MyType * const Test<void>::sm_object = new MyType();`

Comment: I was hoping to make this a header-only component, instead of having a static lib to link against, so I implemented it using the CRTP to hold the static object. Marking as the answer as you're right that it's all about the link properties of template specializations.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you want to do something like this

```
struct MyType { };

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    static const MyType * const sm_object;
    static const MyType* set_object()
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

template <>
struct Test<void>
{
    static const MyType * const sm_object;
    static const MyType* set_object()
    {
        return new MyType();
    }
};

template <typename T> 
const MyType * Test<T>::sm_object = Test< T >::set_object();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code could be of quite some interest for some people:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template<class X,int Y>
struct B
{
  X content;
  static const int nr=Y;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  B<char,1> a;
  B<int,2> b;
  B<int,3> c;
  printf("%d, %d, %d\n",a.nr,b.nr,c.nr);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is quite interesting, but the original question was more about how static members behave during the link phase under explicit specialisation.